# Is a static class shared when referenced from a NuGet package in the main app and a dll?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have a Nuget package with a static class inside it. This package is consumed by a .dll and my main app which in turn also uses the dll. So my question is if any change in state is made to the static class by the main app will it also be reflected in the dll when it tries to use that class.

Suppose the Nuget package contains :

```cs
namespace Package{
   public static class SomeClass{
      public static int A {get; set;}
      public static void Change(int x){ A = x; }
   }
}
```

The main app can be like:

```cs
using Package;

namespace MainApp{
  public static void Main(string[] args){
    SomeClass.Change(5);
    DllClass c = new DllClass();
    Console.WriteLine(c.DllFunc());
  }
}
```

The dll function is defined as:

```cs
using Package;

public class DllClass{
    public DllClass() {}
    public int DllFunc() { return SomeClass.A; }
}
```

Comment: If we're talking about the same process (and AppDomain) then yes, it's the same "memory".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. An assembly is loaded just once for a given AppDomain, and any static initialization of a particular static class occurs the first time it is referenced.

In your sample code, `Package.SomeClass`'s static initializers will run when `MainApp.Main()` kicks off, and then `SomeClass.Change()` will execute. Everybody else sees that change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, static fields (not class) exist only once in the whole application unless you do some funky stuff (like additional AppDomains).

You generally do not share "classes", but rather data that is stored in the fields in these classes.

Static means that you don't need an object to access a class field but rather can access it by class name only, meaning it's only once instance of static data in memory.

Comment: There is *always* an AppDomain—normally, just one per process—but there is always an AppDomain.

Comment: Yes, I just was not clear enough, have edited the text :)